# r bookdown: custom blocks in pdf output with grey background and icon

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

So I spend some hours trying to figure out a way to get the same lightgrey custom block with an icon in my LaTeX output like I did in html with the help of CSS. The LaTex code is fine, since it works in a minimal reproducable example, but it simply does not render correctly when rendering with rMarkdown and the `bookdown` Package. The closest I came is a grey background in the block with a badly aligned icon on the left without a grey background, but want I want is this:

[image]

Here's a short example how it works within usual LaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{f5f5f5}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newenvironment{warning}[1]% #1 = text on left
{\noindent\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,margin=1ex,bgcolor=lightgray,env=center}
    \sbox0{#1}% measure width
    \usebox0\hfill% align baseline with center of minipage
    %\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\dp0-0.5\ht0}{\usebox0}\hfill% align center with center
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}% added \columnsep gap between
}
{%
\end{minipage}\end{adjustbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{warning}{\Huge \faWarning}
I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works. I hope it works.  
\end{warning}

\end{document}
```

Since rMarkdown has a known issue with `xcolor` one could easily change the color to `shadecolor` like they did in [this](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/latex/preamble.tex) example, where I got the code to the closest working solution, yet. But when I render my code within the `preamble.tex` the block gets very very tiny, so that one would have to zoom in like 300x to read the content. Why is that? Whats the reason rMarkdown being so picky which LaTeX code it allows to compile? Does anyone have an idea how to get that working like in Html?

The CSS equivalent would be

```css
div.warning {
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 5em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position:relative;
}

div.warning:before {
  content: "\f071";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  left:10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px center/3em no-repeat;
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

PS: The code that actually works in my `preamble.tex` file but doesn't have a grey background and a bad aligned icon is here:

```latex
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% larger font size for fontawesome icons
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge{30pt}{20}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Grey Blocks
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
    \medskip{}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{.8em}
    \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
    \ifinner\ifhmode%
    \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
    \fi\fi%
    \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
        \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
        % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
        \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
        \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
        \@setminipage}}%
{\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
    \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{Shaded}{
}{\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{kframe}}{\end{kframe}}}
\makeatother
%           \raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{
\newenvironment{rmdblock}[1]
{
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{
            \raisebox{-0.9\height}[0pt][0pt]{
                {\setkeys{Gin}{width=3em,keepaspectratio}\Huge #1}
            }
        }
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
        \begin{kframe}
            \item
        }
        {
        \end{kframe}
    \end{itemize}
}
\newenvironment{warning}
{\begin{rmdblock}{\faWarning}}
    {\end{rmdblock}}
```

giving you this image
[image]